# Beam Splitter: looking for a "not-typical" second quantization but full-quantum description

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

In all the books of Quantum Optics I read, the theory of beam-splitter (BS) is presented in more or less the same way, e.g. introduction of the transmission-reflection matrix, case study of the single photon and vacuum at the BS inputs, or example with the coherent states, or Hong-Ou-Mandel effect.

However, I'm looking for a quantum description of the BS in terms of the interaction between the photons and the atoms, e.g. with the Fermi Golden rule.

Please, can someone point me to some paper and/or book where I could find such description?

Comment: If you wanted to do it "right", then you would have to formulate it in the language of quantum field theory. If you do that, of course, then the only field that has any interest in such a description goes away. Quantum mysticism only "works" because quantum mystics don't use a self-consistent description of the world to raise an aura of mystery.

Comment: @CuriousOne Thank you for your comment! Please, could you elaborate more about "_the only field that has any interest in such a description goes away_ " ?

Comment: I really can't tell you why some people won't accept 80 year old physics that has proven to be correct at all levels. You have to ask them about that.

Comment: @CuriousOne Sorry, but I do not understand the sense of your last comment: what are you meaning?

Comment: That you need to ask the quantum mystics why they aren't using the framework of QFT, it might have something to do with all the magic collapsing once one does. Did you try to use QFT for the beam splitter?

Comment: @CuriousOne sorry but who are these "quantum mystics"? are they people who don't accept 80 years of proven results? I just simply asked for some reference from where transmission/reflection probabilities are expressed in terms of amplitude transition probabilities

Comment: You asked for the correct description of a beam splitter that includes both matter (atoms) and photons. That would be QFT. You can probably stick to quantum electrodynamics and leave the internal structure of nuclei out of it, since you are only going for energies at the 1eV scale.

Comment: @CuriousOne I guess that all these comments you made are biased by the fact that you interpreted "not typical" in the title as "alternative NOT quantum description". And now I understand the sense of the comment "  _ I really can't tell you why some people won't accept 80 year old physics that has proven to be correct at all levels. You have to ask them about that._ ". I am simply looking for a BS description in terms of Fermi Golden rule transition matrix element, as it is usually done to describe the process of photon-detection.

Comment: I told you what you wanted to know. Get a QED textbook and start reading on how to model a system of atoms and photons properly. Once you understand it for one atom, you can combine $10^{23}$ of them into a beamsplitter. Fermi's Golden rule is NOT a correct way to model it. It's just a semi-classical perturbation approximation without any fundamental insight into the microscopic processes.

Comment: @CuriousOne Agreed that Fermi's Golden Rule, it is not the full quantum but only semi-classical. Typically indeed, Quantum Optics books present the photon-detection theory with both these two approaches (semi-classical and full-quantum with QED formalism), e.g. Mandel's and Wolf's bible "Optical Coherence and Quantum Optics", as they consider the single atom interacting with a photon and then with a generalization to a "larger" set of atoms. What I'm looking for is the SAME kind of treatment but "specialized" for BS.  Anyway, thank you for your effort.

Comment: As soon as you want to talk about "photons" you are in QED. A photon is a quantum of an electromagnetic wave. Not sure what else I can tell you... there are many ways to hand wave in physics. Some authors do a classical em wave and then start talking about photons. I wouldn't.

Comment: To the dual nature of photons, a beamsplitter only affects the wave behavior. It does not affect the particle behavior -- it does not absorb or add any photon. Second quantization is not really needed to describe a beamsplitter. But using the $a$ and $a^\dagger$ operators is easier than not.

Answer (score 5):

@TrulyIgnorant

I personally think this is a great question, and surprisingly one that has not yet been fully answered to my knowledge! There are two works that come very close to putting together a first-principles derivation that is fully quantum-mechanical, i.e. by quantizing the modes of a beam-splitter, showing their connection to a Hamiltonian and taking a limit that reproduces the unitary transformation you're referring to.

The papers are:

"Quasi mode theory of the beam splitter-a quantum scattering theory approach" by B. J. Dalton, Stephen M. Barnett & P. L. Knight

combined with

"A quantum scattering theory approach to quantum-optical measurements" B. J. Dalton, Stephen M. Barnett & P. L. Knight

In my advisor's group we're currently working on a tutorial that will go through this quantization and derivation to make it hopefully more clear - I'll try to post back here after we're done. A related question is how precisely to quantize a cavity coupled to the world - Sergio Dutra worked on this problem and distilled it very nicely in his book "Cavity Quantum Electrodynamics".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which I appreciate much more than the useless comments I received earlier. That's exactly what I was looking for and I look forward for reading your tutorial. Thanks again!